# Odoo 9.0 email notifications are not automatically fired

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

Odoo 9.0 email notifications are not automatically fired. I had to manually send one by one. Please see attachment. Could anyone guide me to what need to changed in order to fire these pending emails automatically?
[image]

Comment: Usually there is a CronJob. Is it active?

Comment: Hi, How can I check that? I am using Ubuntu I see no crontab for the user when I typed crontab -l

Comment: A CronJob (Scheduled Action) in Odoo not in your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to settings -> Automation and Check if **Email Queue Manager** is active and you can run it manually or update **Next Execution Date**
[image]